# Buffer Overflow - No available Space crash in Android

Tags: android, crash, buffer-overflow

So, I'm constantly getting this buffer overflow crash (393238).

One example, I've just fixed is, when I run `Log.d("test", null)` I get the crash.

If I remove this line of code, there's no crash.

As far as I know, every single bug in my code, whether it's an `ArrayOutOfBounds`, Incorrect Type, Null Exceptions, etc. are all causing Buffer Overflow crashes.

I don't know why this is happening. Why is Android not gracefully handling and returning Exception messages, rather than crashing the program with a Buffer Overflow message all the time?

Also, I've tried running on my own phone through usb debugging, Nexus emulator, etc. Still happens.

Here is the exact message:

```
W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

Comment: What did you expect by `Log.d("test", null)` ? It does not make any sense, it will throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Yes it should throw a null pointer exception but I get a buffer overflow crash instead. My question is why?

Comment: Try `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Comment: Didn't fix it unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. My app ran fine on my main computer from android studio on both a real android tablet and the tablet emulator. When I did the exact same thing on my laptop I got this crash, for both real device and emulator.

I ended up 'fixing it' by deleting the project build directory, and doing a Tools->AVD Manager->Actions Wipe Data. I then rebuilt/ran the project and it worked. Go figure...